# Why isnt my googleapi client connected, even after I call client.connect()?

Tags: android, google-drive-api, google-drive-android-api

I'm trying to open a file, but it wont let me build the intentsender for some reason. mGoogleApiClient has been called to connect , but it still doesnt. I have a different method, that is used to upload a file, and it works. However that piece of code uses .onResultCallback. I've tried to make openDriveFile() as simple as possible, but it doesnt allow me and I didnt find any implementations that would be of use to me. Any help is appreciated. If you need me to post the code for the other method, ask.

```
public String openDriveFile(){
    final String[] contentsAsString = new String[1];
    if(mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()){
        System.out.println("IS CONNECTED!!!!!");

    }else{
        //connect it
        System.out.println("ISNT CONNECTED!!!!!");
        mGoogleApiClient.connect();

    }
    IntentSender is = Drive.DriveApi.newOpenFileActivityBuilder().setMimeType(new String[] { "text/plain", "text/html" }).build(mGoogleApiClient);

    try {
        startIntentSenderForResult(
                is, 1, null, 0, 0, 0);
    } catch (IntentSender.SendIntentException e) {
        Log.w(TAG, "Unable to send intent", e);
    }
    return contentsAsString[0];
}
```

This is my current code. However I get this error:

```
04-16 19:00:45.156 20896-20896/david.projectclouds E/AndroidRuntime: 
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: david.projectclouds, PID: 20896
                                                                 java.lang.IllegalStateException: Client must be connected
                                                                     at com.google.android.gms.common.internal.zzaa.zza(Unknown Source)
                                                                     at com.google.android.gms.drive.OpenFileActivityBuilder.build(Unknown Source)
                                                                     at david.projectclouds.MainActivity.openDriveFile(MainActivity.java:297)
                                                                     at david.projectclouds.MainActivity$3.onClick(MainActivity.java:182)
                                                                     at android.support.v7.app.AlertController$AlertParams$3.onItemClick(AlertController.java:1045)
                                                                     at android.widget.AdapterView.performItemClick(AdapterView.java:310)
                                                                     at android.widget.AbsListView.performItemClick(AbsListView.java:1219)
                                                                     at android.widget.AbsListView$PerformClick.run(AbsListView.java:3191)
                                                                     at android.widget.AbsListView$3.run(AbsListView.java:4139)
                                                                     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
                                                                     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:241)
                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6217)
                                                                     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:865)
                                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:755)
```

Comment: post your full code...

Answer (score 0):

You need to wait for the client to actually connect. There is a callback method provided by the Google API on connection.

Move all of your code after `mGoogleApiClient.connect();` to this method:

```
@Override
public void onConnected(Bundle bundle) {
 Log.d(TAG, "onConnected() called");
 //...
}
```

Comment: But I need to be listening for a click. Wouldnt putting it in onConnected make it start every time it connects, making me open the file many more times than needed?

Comment: Ok, I see. Then you need to connect and authenticate with the API in your Activity's `onCreate`-method and remove the `} else { //connect` from your `openDriveFile`-method

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
if (isGooglePlayServicesAvailable()){
        if (mGoogleApiClient == null){
            mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                .build();
        }
    }


private boolean isGooglePlayServicesAvailable() {
        final int PLAY_SERVICES_RESOLUTION_REQUEST =9 *1000;
        GoogleApiAvailability googleAPI = GoogleApiAvailability.getInstance();
        int result = googleAPI.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(this);
        if (result !=ConnectionResult.SUCCESS) {
            if (googleAPI.isUserResolvableError(result)) googleAPI.getErrorDialog(this, result, PLAY_SERVICES_RESOLUTION_REQUEST).show();
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I found my problem. It appears that I have to Google Authenticate before using my functions(even if I am signed in). I dont have any idea how I missed this, and I definitely can't leave it like this.